# wxButton covering entire client area C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have made an application using wxWidgets 3.1.5 in C++ and everything is working fine except a test button that I have on my main window.
Here's a pic:
[image]

The menubar, menus and their functions work perfectly but the button covers the entire client area.

Here's the code:

main.h

```
#pragma once
#include <wx\wx.h>
#include "mainFrame.h"

class main : public wxApp
{
private:
    mainFrame* frame;
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(main);

bool main::OnInit()
{
    frame = new mainFrame("Kill Me", wxPoint(15, 10), wxSize(640, 480));
    frame->Show();
    return true;
}
```

mainFrame.h

```
#pragma once
#include "About.h"

using str = std::string;

class mainFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    mainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
    ~mainFrame();
private:
    About* abtF = NULL;

    wxButton* hewwo = NULL;

    wxMenuBar* mbar = NULL;
    wxMenu* sett = NULL;
    wxMenu* quitApp = NULL;
    wxMenu* abt = NULL;

    void onHewwo(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void onSett(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void quit(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void about(wxCommandEvent& evt);

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

enum {
    ID_SETT = 1,
    ID_BTN = 2
};
```

mainFrame.cpp

```
#include "mainFrame.h"

wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(mainFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_BUTTON(ID_BTN, onHewwo)
    EVT_MENU(ID_SETT, onSett)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, quit)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_ABOUT, about)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()


mainFrame::mainFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
    :
    wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) {
    
    hewwo = new wxButton(this, ID_BTN, "Hewwo World", wxPoint(15, 15), wxSize(70, 20));


    sett = new wxMenu();
    sett->AppendSeparator();
    sett->Append(ID_SETT, "&Settings");

    quitApp = new wxMenu();
    quitApp->AppendSeparator();
    quitApp->Append(wxID_EXIT, "&Quit this crap");

    abt = new wxMenu();
    abt->AppendSeparator();
    abt->Append(wxID_ABOUT, "&About");

    mbar = new wxMenuBar();
    mbar->Append(sett, "&Settings");
    mbar->Append(abt, "&About");
    mbar->Append(quitApp, "&Quit");

    SetMenuBar(mbar);
}

void mainFrame::onHewwo(wxCommandEvent& evt) {
    wxMessageBox("Hewwo", "Hewwo", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, this);
}

void mainFrame::onSett(wxCommandEvent& evt) {
    wxMessageBox("Settings", "Settings", wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, this); // Just a test
}

void mainFrame::about(wxCommandEvent& evt) {
    abtF = new About(wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(480, 320));
    abtF->Show();
}

void mainFrame::quit(wxCommandEvent& evt) {
    Close(true);
}

mainFrame::~mainFrame() {
    delete abtF;
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
(I followed OneLoneCoder's (javidx9) youtube video on wxWidgets)

Comment: you don't use sizers? And you have only the button inside the window?

Comment: @Igor yes, I didn't use sizers anywhere in the code, neither in `About.h`. FYI I also tried building and running without `About.h` and the result was the same AND `About.h` included wx\wx.h.

Comment: not sure what this `About.h` is. Just want to point out that you will get a lot of headache without sizers. But that aside - 1 control in the window will fill out its whole client area. What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how a `wxFrame` with only one child behaves.

If you don't want that, use a `wxSizer` to layout your button (position, align, expand etc).

Reference:

> **if the frame has exactly one child window, not counting the status and toolbar, this child is resized to take the entire frame client area**. If two or more windows are present, they should be laid out explicitly either by manually handling wxEVT_SIZE or using sizers

[wxFrame docs](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_frame.html) -> `Default event processing` -> `wxEVT_SIZE`